# Need to solve this

Tags: cipher, pattern

I got a puzzle to solve from the guys at my stag party; and I need it solved by my wedding (next Saturday). I spent hours looking at this but I can't find the solution; can anyone help me?

I got a piece of paper with this on it;

```
1. 57843
2. 32672
3. 5891
4. 1994
5. 36225
6. 87823
8. 42553

A. 6638
B. 1624
C. 4482
D. 2386
E. 1644
F. 2097
H. 4681
```

On the back of that piece of paper there was written: **XHYPZ**.

I also received a key, with written on the keytagg: *csbka*

Can anyone help me solve this?

I received a tip:
If you can put the correct number combinations together; you will easily find the logic.

[image: codes 1]

[image: Codes 2]

[image: Key]

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Could you share the pictures of the piece of paper? I am curious to see if there are any other clues that we may be missing when looking at the rewritten text.

Comment: I noticed that on the paper, the number 7 and the letter G are missing. And if you have a phone with NFC compatibility, maybe you can download some sort off app that reads the tag?

Comment: @David, 7 and G are missing also in the retyped text of the riddle. I think that's indeed a clue, but do not know yet what that means.

Comment: It's now past the deadline - were you able to solve it?

Comment: Indeed, were you able to solve it? Did you read the NFC tag? Did it have something to do with the intrusion panel key? If this is solvable for people without internal knowledge, then let us know, give us all the information that is needed to solve it and I am sure people will find pleasure in trying solving it :-)

Answer (score 2):

XHYPZ

csbka

the keys are suggesting that

a maps to Z
b maps to Y
c maps to X
d maps to W
e maps to V
f maps to U
g maps to T
h maps to S
i maps to R
j maps to Q
k maps to P

right?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling!. At the moment this seems more like a comment than a solution. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you; looks like we're getting somewhere

Comment: This is certainly not a coincidence. However, I cannot make the connection between the numbers.

Comment: Added the pictures. Got some feedback about Kanyan's approach; we're getting warm.
I also got another tip; I work in security; and our intrusion control panels are identified by a alphanumeric key; using a fixed format: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx; e.g.: fdb23-h3xb6-12q4. One of the guys said, hey; looks like an intrusion panel key.... (wink wink).
Also, the key tag on the key is a proximity acces tang; someone said it's ID is also of importance; so I will read it out this evening.

Answer (score 0):

A1    common digits     8, 3

B2    common digits     6, 2

C3    common digit      8

F6     common digit    7

H7    common digit    4

A1, B2, C3, F6, H7 are the answer.

On a push button phone the key has 3 letters on number 2 and the capital letters have 3  letters on number 9. The capital letters have one letter on number 4 and the key one letter on number 5 they both share a letter on number 7 of the push button phone. So the answer is 245779.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't take the 2 keys into account;
XHYPZ

csbka

Comment: @David vary. David it does now.